# No route matches [DELETE] "/relations" when sending an xhr request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the request:

```
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('utf8', true);
      formData.append('relation[from_id]', event.target.data('source'));
      formData.append('relation[to_id]', event.target.data('target'));
      formData.append('relation[graph]', 1);
      formData.append('commit', "Destroy+Relation");

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("DELETE", `/relations/`);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");

      xhr.send(formData);
```

This is the route:

```
delete 'relations/destroy'
```

This is the controller code:

```
  def destroy
    @relation = Relation.find_or_create_by(relation_params)
    @relation.user.remove(current_user)
    @relation.save
    if @relation.user.empty? then @relation.destroy end
  end
```

This is the error I get:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/relations"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your route as `relations/destroy`, but you're trying to reach it using `/relations/`. If you do:

```
xhr.open("DELETE", '/relations/destroy');
```

It's probably gonna work.